# Android: Sub-class Gallery doesn't scroll by onKeyDown event

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a sub-classed Gallery widget which I customized its onFling method, otherwise everything should be the same as the original Gallery widget.

And I am trying to animate its scrolling left or right by using:

```
gallery.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, new KeyEvent(0, 0));
```

But that doesn't seems to work on the sub-class Gallery. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

If you guys have this problem, try get rid of the gallery spacing value -- that solved it for me.

Comment: I had the same problem, and it was solved by removing the spacing value for me too. Really crazy stuff.