# Gallery scrolling with onKeyDown and spacing

Tags: android, gallery, spacing, onkeydown

Im trying to animate a gallery scrolling when pressing two buttons:

```
gallery.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, new KeyEvent(0, 0))
```

or

```
gallery.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, new KeyEvent(0, 0))
```

Didnt worked well on Galaxy Nexus S, prefect on Galaxy Note though.

I've read this:

[Android: Sub-class Gallery doesn't scroll by onKeyDown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801700/android-sub-class-gallery-doesnt-scroll-by-onkeydown-event)

The solution is to delete the spacing in the gallery. However, i need to keep it. Any trick for that?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the gallery doesn't know a position of a next view, it is not visible yet. You need to scroll to overcome spacing and then the view becomes visible and you can use onKeyDown.

Just look at this [Setting any value for Gallery spacing will disable onKeyEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027205/setting-any-value-for-gallery-spacing-will-disable-onkeyevent)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by use negative number -1 as the argument of method setSpacing(). which is **setSpacing(-1)**